# What would cause Android ANR that references unused Sentry library?

Tags: android, sentry, anr

I'm getting a lot  of ANRs in my android app. There is a SDK provider note in the Play console with this information.

> Provided by Sentry Android Core io.sentry:sentry-android-core Feb 28,
> 2023
>
> Crash status Known issue (won't fix)
>
> Note The issue is either
> caused by the consumer application or by the Android SDK itself, our
> WindowCallbackAdapter stack frames just happened to be there because
> of our UI breadcrumbs instrumentation. The WindowCallbackAdapter does
> not do anything besides delegating the call to the next
> Window.Callback.
> https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-android-core/src/main/java/io/sentry/android/core/internal/gestures/WindowCallbackAdapter.java

I don't use Sentry in the app. I thought it my be from a library but I did a Gradle dependency search and couldn't find a reference. I do use Admob. Could this be loaded from a WebView by an ad provider? Has anyone else had this issue? I don't know what code to show since there are no references to any app code.

Comment: are you sure you don't have a sentry dependency in your app (maybe transitively)? The WebView is not the culprit here, as this stackframe is within our Android SDK, and not the web SDK. If you don't have the SDK in your app, then it must be a Google Play Console issue that they shouldn't have surfaced this to you.